# Why is PGFPlots not respecting my axis name placement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

PGFPlots isn't respecting my axis label placement. Why is `x label style={at={(...)}}` (and analogously for the *y* axis) not working?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false,every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.024,0.5)},anchor=east}}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=0.9*\textwidth,
                height=0.9*\textwidth,
                axis line style=thick,
                xmin=-4,
                xmax=4,
                x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
                xlabel=$x$,
                axis x line=middle,
                ymin=-4,
                ymax=4,
                y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south,rotate=-90},
                ylabel=$y$,
                axis y line=center,
                disabledatascaling
            ]
                \addplot[smooth,thick,red,domain=-4:4]{(1/10)*x^3};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The placement option `current axis.right of origin` should make the horizontal axis label appear to the right of the axis, not above it, and the placement option `current axis.above origin` should make the vertical axis label appear above the axis, not next to it.

Setting `axis x line=bottom` or `axis y line=left` fixes the label placement for the corresponding axis, but it moves the axis line to the edge of the graph, which I don't want.

Why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the option with e.g. `axis x line=middle`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.9*\textwidth,
height=0.9*\textwidth,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style=thick,
xmin=-4, xmax=4,
ymin=-4, ymax=4,
xlabel=$x$,
x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, anchor=west},
ylabel=$y$,
y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, anchor=east, rotate=-90},
]
\addplot[smooth, thick, red, domain=-4:4]{(1/10)*x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with axis labels]

Comment: Well, thanks! It's also easier to set the axis positions with a single line of code than with two (assuming I want both in the middle, which in this case I do). I spent hours today on this and you solved it in no time!